# How do I find my network SSID?

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, wifi

I would like to install Arch Linux. In the first part of the installation, I need to connect to a wireless LAN network. But I don't know what my network's SSID is.

How can I find this out?

Comment: Please read the Arch Wiki, there is a [step by step guide to setting up wireless](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless#Access_point_discovery)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm guessing the real problem is that you don't know what a [SSID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_(802.11_network)#Service_set_identifier) is.  It's the technical term for the network's name, i.e. the thing that shows up in a listing of available networks.

If you don't know what network you're supposed to connect to, you'll have to ask somebody at your location.  If you have a WiFi router, it probably has its default SSID printed on a sticker somewhere on it.

As the [Arch wiki explains](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration/Wireless#Discover_access_points), you can get a list of available networks with the command

```
iw dev wlan0 scan
```

(where `wlan0` is whatever your wireless device is named).

Answer (score 2):

It can be hard to find your wireless router if you have a hidden SSID.

You need to give your network manager a little help. Try this:

iwconfig wlan0 essid "myRouterName"

Then you can search for it:

Arch: wifi-menu
Debian: iwlist wlan0 | grep "myRouterName"